# Spacemacs helm-org layer is missing

Tags: spacemacs, helm

Good day,

I wanted to use the helm-org-in-buffer-headings function. Yet for some reason helm-org layer is missing. If I install it manually via package list packages it gets deleted with the next start of spacemacs.

How could I get helm-org to work? Maybe I should completely reinstall helm? If I put helm in configuration layers unfortunately helm-org doesn't install.
The helm besides the helm-org seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `helm-org` is not part of the `helm` layer, you can add it to your personal configuration manually. Add the package name to the `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` list in your `.spacemacs` file. If you find a nice way to configure it, consider learning a bit about how Spacemacs layers work and add the package to the existing helm layer configuration ;)

Spacemacs is configured to delete any package that does not belong to a layer and isn't in this list. I was confused by this at first too, but now I consider it a nice feature. It allows you to install and audit a package and then have it cleanly removed if you don't like it and want it around anymore.

Comment: If I add the helm-org in this way it produces the reoccuring error 'Error running timer `org-indent-initialize-agent`: (void-function org-time-add) [17 times]'. Also `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` shows only nil results instead of meaningful headings.

Comment: are you on the `master` or `develop` branch? i just installed `helm-org` and i'm not seeing that `org-indent-intialize-agent` error.  you could try recompiling the org package directory, that might fix that error.  i am seeing the `nil` results, but i'm not sure how to setup the package yet.

Comment: okay, well i tried installing `helm` and `helm-org` in a vanilla emacs install and the nil headings doesn't happen. i thought maybe the `org-bullets` package installed with spacemacs was causing the error, but i excluded it and it still didn't work.  I would recommend opening an issue on the Spacemacs github and see if anyone can help out.  in the meantime, you can try `helm-org-rifle` and its various functions to see if you can get the functionality you need with a different package?

Comment: Issue submitted: [Git issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/13014)

Comment: @Rareform - sounds like there was an issue between an updated version of `org` and `helm-org`.  `helm-org` has been updated and it seems to work with spacemacs now.

Comment: Since the issue was cleared I mark the answer as accepted. I've learned from this thread, that the develop branch might often be more stable and better functioning, despite the logical expectation that master should be more stable.